# Programmatically execute a Python file from within Python in a fresh-looking Python environment

Tags: python, python-import, python-importlib, python-exec, pyfakefs

Let's say I have a file `script.py` located at `path = "foo/bar/script.py"`. I'm looking for a way in Python to programmatically execute `script.py` from within my main Python program through a function `execute_script()`. However, I've got a few requirements that seem to prevent me from employing a naive approach involving `importlib` or `exec()`:

- `script.py` should get executed in a "fresh-looking" Python environment as if it were run through `$ python script.py`. That is, all relevant globals like `__name__`, `__file__`, `sys.modules`, `sys.path` and the working directory should be set accordingly and as little information as possible should leak from my main program into the file's execution. (It is okay, though, if `script.py` could find out through the `inspect` module that it wasn't executed through `$ python script.py` directly.)
- I need access to the result of the execution, i.e. `execute_script()` should return the module given by `script.py` with all its variables, functions and classes. (This prevents starting a new Python interpreter in a subprocess.)
- `execute_script()` must internally use `open()` to read in `script.py`. This is so that I can use the `pyfakefs` package to mock out the file system during unit tests. (This prevents a simple solution involving importlib.)
- `execute_script()` must not (permanently) modify any global state in my main program like `sys.path` or `sys.modules`.
- If possible, `script.py` should not be able to affect my main program's global state. (At the very least it should not be able to affect `sys.path` and `sys.modules` in my main program.)
- I need to be able to modify the `sys.path` that `script.py` sees. `execute_function()` should therefore accept an optional list of system paths as argument.
- Stack traces and handling of errors occurring during the execution of `script.py` should work as usual. (This makes a solution involving `exec()` difficult.)
- The solution should be as future-proof as possible and not depend on implementation details of the Python interpreter.

I'd be very grateful for any ideas!

Answer (score 2):

I just came across the fact that `exec()` also accepts code objects (that can be obtained e.g. from `compile()`) and have come up with an approach that seems to fulfill nearly all requirements. "nearly" because with the exception of `sys.path` and `sys.modules` the script can still affect the global state of the main program. Moreover, it also gets to see all modules that are imported before `execute_script()` is called. For the time being I'm happy with this, though.

Here is the full code including tests:

```
import os
import sys
from typing import List


module = os.__class__


def create_module(name: str, file: str) -> module:
    mod = module(name)
    # Instances of `module` automatically come with properties __doc__,
    # __loader__, __name__, __package__ and __spec___. Let's add some
    # more properties that main modules usually come with:

    mod.__annotations__ = {}
    # __builtins__ doesn't show up in dir() but still exists
    mod.__builtins__ = __builtins__
    mod.__file__ = file

    return mod


def exec_script(path: str, working_dir: str, syspath: List[str] = None) -> module:
    """
    Execute a Python script as if it were executed using `$ python
    <path>` from inside the given working directory. `path` can either
    be an absolute path or a path relative to `working_dir`.

    If `syspath` is provided, a copy of it will be used as `sys.path`
    during execution. Otherwise, `sys.path` will be set to
    `sys.path[1:]` which – assuming that `sys.path` has not been
    modified so far – removes the working directory from the time when
    the current Python program was started. Either way, the directory
    containing the script at `path` will always be added at position 0
    in `sys.path` afterwards, so as to simulate execution via `$ python
    <path>`.
    """

    if os.path.isabs(path):
        abs_path = path
    else:
        abs_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(working_dir), path)

    with open(abs_path, "r") as f:
        source = f.read()

    if sys.version_info < (3, 9):
        # Prior to Python 3.9, the __file__ variable inside the main
        # module always contained the path exactly as it was given to `$
        # python`, no matter whether it is relative or absolute and/or a
        # symlink.
        the__file__ = path
    else:
        # Starting from Python 3.9, __file__ inside the main module is
        # always an absolute path.
        the__file__ = abs_path

    # The filename passed to compile() will be used in stack traces and
    # error messages. It normally it agrees with __file__.
    code = compile(source, filename=the__file__, mode="exec")

    sysmodules_backup = sys.modules
    sys.modules = sys.modules.copy()
    the_module = create_module(name="__main__", file=the__file__)
    sys.modules["__main__"] = the_module

    # According to
    # https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path
    # if the script is a symlink, the symlink is followed before the
    # directory containing the script is added to sys.path.
    if os.path.islink(abs_path):
        sys_path_dir = os.path.dirname(os.readlink(abs_path))
    else:
        sys_path_dir = os.path.dirname(abs_path)

    if syspath is None:
        syspath = sys.path[1:]
    syspath_backup = sys.path
    sys.path = [
        sys_path_dir
    ] + syspath  # This will automatically create a copy of syspath

    cwd_backup = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(working_dir)

    # For code inside a module, global and local variables are given by
    # the *same* dictionary
    globals_ = the_module.__dict__
    locals_ = the_module.__dict__
    exec(code, globals_, locals_)

    os.chdir(cwd_backup)
    sys.modules = sysmodules_backup
    sys.path = syspath_backup

    return the_module


#################
##### Tests #####
#################

# Make sure to install pyfakefs via pip!

import unittest

import pyfakefs


class Test_exec_script(pyfakefs.fake_filesystem_unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.setUpPyfakefs()
        self.fs.create_file(
            "/folder/script.py",
            contents="\n".join(
                [
                    "import os",
                    "import sys",
                    "",
                    "cwd = os.getcwd()",
                    "sysmodules = sys.modules",
                    "syspath = sys.path",
                    "",
                    "sys.modules['test_module'] = 'bar'",
                    "sys.path.append('/some/path')",
                ]
            ),
        )
        self.fs.create_symlink("/folder2/symlink.py", "/folder/script.py")

    #
    # __name__
    #
    def test__name__is_set_correctly(self):
        module = exec_script("script.py", "/folder")

        assert module.__name__ == "__main__"

    #
    # __file__
    #
    def test_relative_path_works_and__file__shows_it(self):
        module = exec_script("script.py", "/folder")

        assert module.__file__ == "script.py"

    def test_absolute_path_works_and__file__shows_it(self):
        module = exec_script("/folder/script.py", "/folder")

        assert module.__file__ == "/folder/script.py"

    def test__file__doesnt_follow_symlink(self):
        module = exec_script("symlink.py", "/folder2")

        assert module.__file__ == "symlink.py"

    #
    # working dir
    #
    def test_working_directory_is_set_and_reset_correctly(self):
        os.chdir("/")

        module = exec_script("/folder/script.py", "/folder")

        assert module.cwd == "/folder"
        assert os.getcwd() == "/"

    #
    # sys.modules
    #
    def test__main__module_is_set_correctly(self):
        module = exec_script("/folder/script.py", "/folder")

        assert module.sysmodules["__main__"] == module

    def test_script_cannot_modify_our_sys_modules(self):
        sysmodules_backup = sys.modules.copy()

        exec_script("/folder/script.py", "/folder")

        assert sys.modules == sysmodules_backup

    #
    # sys.path
    #
    def test_script_cannot_modify_our_sys_path(self):
        syspath_backup = sys.path.copy()

        exec_script("/folder/script.py", "/folder")

        assert sys.path == syspath_backup

    def test_sys_path_is_set_up_correctly(self):
        syspath_backup = sys.path[:]
        module = exec_script("/folder/script.py", "/folder")

        assert module.syspath[0] == "/folder"
        assert module.syspath[1:] == syspath_backup[1:] + ["/some/path"]

    def test_symlink_is_followed_before_adding_base_dir_to_sys_path(self):
        module = exec_script("symlink.py", "/folder2")

        assert module.syspath[0] == "/folder"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```